# How can I document implicit methods inside of rails models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, documentation, rdoc, yard

I'm using [YARD](http://yardoc.org) on my Rails project and was wondering how I would go about documenting inherited/runtime methods on a Rails model? For instance documenting the existence of a `first_name` attribute on a `User` model.

Comment: http://gilesbowkett.blogspot.com/2008/02/activerecord-ruby2ruby-this-is-where.html Ruby2Ruby might be helpful, but you'd have to make up your own rdoc generating workflow, `gem rdoc your_project` most likely wouldn't work unless you did some crazy fork of rdoc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that, IMHO.

The trouble is that those methods don't really "exist"; They are "created on the fly" via `method_missing` hooks, the first time they are invoked, on runtime.

Other documentation generation systems have ways to declare "implicit" methods. For example NaturalDocs has a [function keyword](http://www.naturaldocs.org/keywords.html) that allows you to create functions that only exist on the comments. I'm not familiar enough with YARD, but it seems it doesn't have a similar functionality.

Good luck!